# VBA - Format Name

Tags: vba, excel

I am hoping someone can help me in my dilemma. Due to a system software limitation, I need to have all my code in one Macro.

1.) take Column Q which is a name in the format "***last, first***" and break it up using text to column (some names contain initials which is why I used text to column)
2.) include code to dismiss the message box that appears "Do you want to replace the contents of the destination cells?"
3.) delete all columns that are generated except the "last" & "first" name.
4.) concatenate  the two columns so that they read Firstname Lastname
5.) auto fill down to the last row.
6.) copy paste special the values into an adjacent column and delete the old column with the function.

I tried recording the code but it seems that what I need can't be recorded and needs to be written.

Here's my shot at get those steps to work, pulled from code from my recorder as well as forums, and think I need a trained eye to sort through my mess:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Columns("Q:Q").Select
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("Q1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=True, _
    Semicolon:=True, Comma:=True, Space:=True, Other:=False, FieldInfo:= _
    Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:= _
    True

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Columns("U:U").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Columns("S:T").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("S2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(RC[-1], "" "", RC[-2])"
Range("S2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("S2:500")
Range("S2:S42").Select
Columns("S:S").Select
Selection.Copy
Columns("T:T").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Range("T1").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Lead Recruiter"
Columns("Q:S").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
```

Thanks to Ron, I was able to get the msg box to dismiss. Right now it's break at the line:

```
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("S2:500")
```

How can I update this to Autofill to the last row? The data is in column Q. Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: To prevent the message box from popping up, merely add **Application.DisplayAlerts = False** statement before the text to columns code, and **Application.DisplayAlerts = True** somewhere after.  The rest of your question is too broad, and does not contain sufficient information to allow others to reproduce your problem.  I would suggest reading help for information as to how to ask a question, and how to create a minimal and verifiable example of what you require.

Comment: Hi @Ron thank you for the display alerts. That is working like a charm and now it seems to code is breaking at: Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("S2 & lastRow"). I used this DIM above it, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong with the DIM here. Any idea?
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("S2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("S2:S" & lastRow)

Comment: As I wrote before, *The rest of your question is too broad, and does not contain sufficient information to allow others to reproduce your problem. I would suggest reading HELP for information as to how to ask a question, and how to create a minimal and verifiable example of what you require.* If you look at the top of the page, you will see a link to Help

Comment: Which column is the data in? Col Q?

Comment: Hi @SiddharthRout the data is in Q, which is a name in the format "Last, First", but also variably "Last, First M."

Comment: Do you have any data in columns after col Q?

Comment: @SiddharthRout there is Data after column Q, I just modified and ran it and it works like a charm. One quick update, is that after this code runs, I need to run it again in Column T, same exact scenario. I tried simply copy and pasting the same code and modifying the references to columns again but its causing some issues. Is there something I'm missing in order to run it twice?

Comment: A simple modification would have helped. What exact problem are you facing?

Comment: @SiddharthRout Seems to be a compile error at the second "Dim ws As Worksheet". I Simply copied Code 2 twice in one Sub. And updated the column references to start with Column T versus Q in the second code reference.

Comment: You need to dim it only once :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout  I finally figured what's occurring, although not sure how to fix. Here's a file with Sample Data and your revised code, you can run this and see what's occuring. Essentially from what I figured out, the data in column Q vs T is slightly different, in that the data in column T has no (,) in it and I believe that's what part of the formula you wrote searches for. The data in T is in the format "LastName FirstName (00900123123). Any thoughts on how to get it to work for the different data type?https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B2X2dLMa6rYoc2JMNHEwYW5iaGM/edit

Answer (score 3):

**My Assumptions**

1. Data is in Column Q
2. There is no data after Column Q
3. The results needs to be generated in Column R. If you want to replace the values in Column Q then see CODE 2.

Here is the shortest code that I could think of.

**CODE 1**

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        '~~> Find the last row in a column
        lRow = .Range("Q" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        '~~> Enter the formula in the complete column
        .Range("R1:R" & lRow).Formula = "=IFERROR(MID(Q1,FIND("","",Q1,1)+2,FIND("" "",Q1,FIND("","",Q1,1)+2)-" & _
                                        "(FIND("","",Q1,1)+2)),MID(Q1,FIND("","",Q1,1)+2,LEN(Q1)-FIND("","",Q1" & _
                                        ",1)+2+1)) & "" "" & LEFT(Q1,FIND("","",Q1,1)-1)"

        '~~> Convert all formulas to values in one go
        .Range("R1:R" & lRow).Value = .Range("R1:R" & lRow).Value
    End With
End Sub
```

**ScreenShot**

[image]

**CODE 2**

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        '~~> Find the last row in a column
        lRow = .Range("Q" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        '~~> Enter the formula in the complete column
        .Range("R1:R" & lRow).Formula = "=IFERROR(MID(Q1,FIND("","",Q1,1)+2,FIND("" "",Q1,FIND("","",Q1,1)+2)-" & _
                                        "(FIND("","",Q1,1)+2)),MID(Q1,FIND("","",Q1,1)+2,LEN(Q1)-FIND("","",Q1" & _
                                        ",1)+2+1)) & "" "" & LEFT(Q1,FIND("","",Q1,1)-1)"

        '~~> Convert all formulas to values in one go
        .Range("R1:R" & lRow).Value = .Range("R1:R" & lRow).Value

        '~~> Delete Col Q so R moves to Q
        .Columns(17).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

**Followup from Comments**

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub FormatPushReport()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws

        .Range("R:R,U:U").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        .Range("R1").Value = .Range("Q1").Value
        .Range("V1").Value = .Range("U1").Value

        '~~> Find the last row in a column
        lRow = .Range("Q" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


        '~~> Enter the formula in the complete column
        .Range("R2:R" & lRow).Formula = "=IFERROR(MID(Q2,FIND("","",Q2,1)+2,FIND("" "",Q2,FIND("","",Q2,1)+2)-" & _
                                        "(FIND("","",Q2,1)+2)),MID(Q2,FIND("","",Q2,1)+2,LEN(Q2)-FIND("","",Q2" & _
                                        ",1)+2+1)) & "" "" & LEFT(Q2,FIND("","",Q2,1)-1)"

        .Range("V2:V" & lRow).Formula = "=IFERROR(MID(U2,FIND("","",U2,1)+2,FIND("" "",U2,FIND("","",U2,1)+2)-" & _
                                        "(FIND("","",U2,1)+2)),MID(U2,FIND("","",U2,1)+2,LEN(U2)-FIND("","",U2" & _
                                        ",1)+2+1)) & "" "" & LEFT(U2,FIND("","",U2,1)-1)"

        '~~> Convert all formulas to values in one go
        .Range("R2:R" & lRow).Value = .Range("R2:R" & lRow).Value
        .Range("V2:V" & lRow).Value = .Range("V2:V" & lRow).Value

        .Columns(18).Replace What:="#VALUE!", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

        .Columns(22).Replace What:="#VALUE!", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

        .Range("Q:Q,U:U").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    End With
End Sub
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: I only realized after why looping it the second time wasn't working. It seems the assumption that there was no data after Column Q is what's breaking the second loop. I didn't realize Code 2 was overwriting what was in Column R. Any thoughts on how to update this so that it doesn't do this? I tried adding a column so that formula would not over write Column R but it seems now I am getting a #VALUE error with the out put of data after the macro runs.

Comment: I am sorry. I don't understand. Can I see a sample file?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2X2dLMa6rYoWVNsSmxEMkhLd1k/edit?usp=sharing

there are 2 tabs, the sample data which is the raw one and the output, which is what I received after I had inserted the code to add columns, but I removed that from the macro I sent you.